# Can't find DOM element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm going insane. Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ndH9G/4/

It's the relevant code from a Rails site I'm working on (for fantasy football). Every time the "type" select is changed, I want to reset the "Direction" select to "Select" to cut down on the wonkiness that happens if the type is changed after the fields are filled in.

Except I can't.

No matter what I do, I cannot access that stupid "Direction" select. If you look, you'll see these two lines:

```
$('div', location).next('.player-trade-fields').hide();
$('div', location).next('.terms-field').show();
```

And coming as a shock to no one: those work exactly as they should without issue. But when I try to access the "Direction" select which is at the same DOM level as those two fields:

```
$('div', location).next('.trade-direction')
```

I get nothing. I have the alert in there to show me if a value is being returned and absolutely nothing I do returns a value. I don't get it. I don't get how jQuery just will not find it. I've tried:

```
location.next
selectBox.next
$('div', selectBox).next
$('div', selectBox.parent()).next
$('div', selectBox.parent().parent()).next
$('div', selectBox.parent().parent().parent()).next
$('div', selectBox.parent().parent().parent().parent()).next
```

Nothing works. I cannot get that select no matter what I do and after 2 hours of time completely wasted on something that, as far as I can tell, should be working without issue much like the code for the fields at the same level is, I give up.

Please show me whatever the obvious thing I've overlooked is.

Comment: Do you understand that `.next(selector)` ONLY looks at the next sibling (at the same level) and evaluates that one DOM object to see if it matches the selector.  If that one sibling doesn't match the selector, the jQuery object it returns is empty.  It does NOT look through other siblings to find something that matches that selector.  This is a common misconception about how `.next()` works.  You might want to use `.nextAll(selector)` or `.nextAll(selector).first()` instead.

Comment: You can also use `.siblings('...').first()`

Comment: Then why does the exact same syntax work fine for finding the other fields?

Comment: What I mean by that is, choose someone from the top dropdown. Then select "Player" from the type. And choose either "To" or "From" in the direction field. Then, change the "Type" to be something else. You'll notice that the terms and player dropdowns hide/show depending on that. And both the terms and players fields are accessed using $('div', location).next('.player-trade-fields').hide();
$('div', location).next('.terms-field').show(); and are on the same "level" in the DOM as the direction box. But using the same syntax results in "undefined" over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I changed it to:

```
$('div', location).find('.trade-direction')
```

And it's working exactly as it should be and isn't interfering when there are multiple instances of this form on the page added through ajax.

Comment: FYI, your HTML would be a WHOLE lot easier to read if it was all properly indented (I've been unable to follow the hiearchy at all on my small screen laptop).  `$('div', location).find('.trade-direction')` is probably very inefficient because you're doing a separate find below every div in location which is likely not even close to efficient.  Can you just do `location.find('.trade-direction')`?

Comment: It is on the actual site...I have no idea why it's such a mess after being pasted into JSFiddle. I also realized that the player-trade-fields and terms-fields classes were on divs around those fields, not the field itself, so I'm sure that had something to do with the reason the code wasn't working. I know .find() isn't the best solution but, for now, it's working and that's all I care about.